# Unity: Calculate angular velocity of rigidbody to always face specific direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, velocity

I'm trying to make a pick up objects mechanic like the one in Amnesia. It's easy to calculate needed rigidbody's velocity, so that the held object stays in front of camera, but my problem is that the object doesn't rotate at all when I hold it. And I would rather have it always be rotated towards the camera. This could easily be achieved with simply parenting the object to player's camera, but...

The behaviour I'm after is as follows: if the bottle I picked up was standing on a table, with neck of the bottle facing ceiling, I would like to see this bottle always with its neck facing ceiling while I hold it. But if this bottle collides with something, it should behave like it actually bumped onto something, so it should rotate some small amount, but it should always try to return to its "original" rotation (in this case, neck facing ceiling).

I think that I need to calculate angular velocity for that and probably have some lerp to return to original rotation, but I'm at a loss on how to do that properly.

I think that the first thing I would need to do is to store the initial direction the moment player picks object up:

```
Vector3 targetDirection = playerCamera.transform.position - transform.position;
```

Script is on the held object, so "transform" refers to it. In FixedUpdate() I probably need to have some interpolation, so that angular velocity always tries to rotate the object to original rotation:

```
rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.Lerp(rigidbody.angularVelocity, targetAngularVelocity, lerpSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

I don't know how to calculate targetAngularVelocity, because after all I would like the held object to return to original rotation smoothly. I'm not even sure if that's the right way to do this thing and perhaps I should do something else than to calculate angular velocity needed to rotate object properly. I tried just interpolating localRotation to original local rotation, but that did not allow the held object to bump on stuff (the movement then was very jittery). Any ideas?

Comment: Is simply using [`rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) not an option?

Comment: As I said, perhaps I don't need to calculate angular velocity for this. I could use MoveRotation(), but still I'm not sure how to code the behaviour I described.

Answer (score 0):

You need a stabilizer. A script which will add torque/angular velocity to the object, whose angle is different from the target one. Say, you have two variables: `targetDirection` and `currentDirection` aka `transform.forward`. Then you write something like this in fixed update:

```
var rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(currentDirection, targetDirection).eulerAngles * sensitivity;
rigidbody.angularVelocity = rotation;
```

I recommend to set sensitivity about 0.05 and then increase it if the object stabilizes too slow.
Probably I confused the order, so you should put minus somewhere, but the approach itself is applicable.

Comment: Thanks! But I think it should be something else than Vector3.SignedAngle() as it returns float and angularVelocity is Vector3. Perhaps you meant Vector3.Lerp()?

Comment: Oh, I edited the answer

Comment: Seems like we're still missing something. With Quaternion.FromToRotation() the held object just rotates constantly, never reaches its original rotation.

I tried putting different stuff under currentDirection and targetDirection, like transform.forward or (PlayerCam.transform.position - transform.position), but nothing seems to work properly.

Comment: Do you mean `rotation` instead of `angle` ?

Comment: Ah, yes. I just renamed variable to be consistent with it’s meaning)

Comment: This can't be right: rotation is a Quaternion and angularVelocity is a Vector3 and there is no implicit conversion...

Comment: @David `rotation` isn't a Quaternion: check the very end of the line, he converts it to eulerAngles before multiplying by `sensitivity`. So it's a Vector3, and can thus be assigned to the property in the next line.